# NTAG 424 SDMENCFileData use-case

Tags: nfc, ndef

I've been burying my nose in the [AN12196.pdf](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf) for a few days now and slowly getting a hang of it.

What I cannot clearly understand is the idea behind the **SDMENCFileData**.

In section **4.4.3 SDMENCFileData mirror**, if I understand it correctly, it's saying that you can take any 32-character plaintext part of your URL, and it gets encrypted when tapping, am I right?

What would be the use-case of this? If I had some secret thing, that's shorter than 32-chars, I have to pad it before encrypting, and if I had something longer I wouldn't be able to use it. I wanted to know what other's use this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Secure Dynamic Messaging** (SDM) or **Secure Unique NFC** feature is an amazing one available on NTAG 424 DNA and Mifare DESFire EV3 tags.

If enabled it allows to work with NFC card readers that can read a standardized NDEF message without any dedicated app. The card reader should forward the "Link/URI" NDEF message to a browser that connects to a backend server. This backend server gets the data transferred within the link.

For an example I'm storing this link on a NTAG 424 DNA NDEF file (that is a Standard file):

```
https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tag?picc_data=00000000000000000000000000000000&enc=0102030405060708A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8&cmac=00000000000000
```

Without enabled SDM/SUN feature this link is calling the backend server in Plain communication (without any encryption).

Please note: the data you are asking for is the one after the "&enc=" trailer:

`0102030405060708A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8`

where only the first half of them will be encrypted later, the second half is a placeholder for the complete encrypted data as they are encoded in hex encoding.

What does happen when the SDM/SUN feature gets enabled ? This is same data but in encrypted form:

```
https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tag?picc_data=B825283ABE4DDCE04C86DC9D078F927D&enc=AD5B1FE8F6CBA426B3CF522CAC77A695&cmac=5F5FB0752DD549F4
```

The data behind the "&enc=" trailer is now:

`AD5B1FE8F6CBA426B3CF522CAC77A695`

This is the encrypted first half of the plaintext shown before.

Now run a live test with a sample backend server. Below you find the same url as clickable link that will bring you to a backend server that is. been able to decrypt the data:

https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/tag?picc_data=B825283ABE4DDCE04C86DC9D078F927D&enc=AD5B1FE8F6CBA426B3CF522CAC77A695&cmac=5F5FB0752DD549F4

The result is as follows:

```
Secure Dynamic Messaging Backend Server Demo
Cryptographic signature validated.

Encryption mode: AES
PICC Data Tag: c7
NFC TAG UID: 04514032501490
Read counter: 4
File data (hex): 30313032303330343035303630373038
File data (UTF-8): 0102030405060708
```

The use case is simple - maybe you like to transport additional data beneath the UID a Read Counter to the backend server (e.g. a birth date for age verification, a promotion code or "vip status").

If your data is shorter than 16 byte just a (random ?) padding, if it is longer you need an additional 32 bytes long spaceholder (in total multiples of 32).

Comment: thank you for the answer!

0102030405060708|A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8 -- does this mean the 2nd half (padding) can be any character? what if they are all '-'? after decrypting `enc` do they come back as '-'? what if your secret data was longer than half like this `010203040506070809--------------` would that still work?

Comment: I didn't think about the use-cases you said because I thought those kinds of information were supposed to be already on the database linked to the NFC tag uid. So there was no point putting them on the card. I couldn't think of anything else but it's a good feature nonetheless.

Comment: Can you please put an example where the secret data is longer than 16 bytes?

Comment: In my work I just used 16 bytes of plaintext that gets 32 bytes (hex encoded string) so if you do have for e.g. 20 bytes of plaintext you pad them up to 32 bytes and use a placeholder of 64 bytes. Only the firt half (in this case 32 bytes) get encrypted and transported to the link -> background server, the second half is "RFU" meaning you can write what you want as placeholder. Please keep in mind that the storage size on a NTAG 424 DNA is limited to about 250 bytes for this file AND an URL should be not oversized to avoid any data loss.

Comment: Regarding the use case: the "main" database may not be at the same place where the background server is so if e.g. a birthday is in the encrypted data the server can easily verify the age without a connection to a database. If you find my answer useful please mark it as accepted one, thanks.

Comment: When you say first half gets encrypted, that confused me. In your example you padded `0102030405060708` with `A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8` but all 32 characters got encrypted (`enc`).

Comment: No, only the first part get encryped (see the output on sdm.nfcdeveloper.com), the second part is padding data only.

Comment: Are you saying after decrypting `enc` you don't get the padding back?

Comment: In the first step the "data to encrypt" is "converted" to a hex string (in my example "0102030405060708" it is 8 bytes converted to 16 hex encoded characters). Only this gets encrypted but for this there are in total 32 hex encoded characters are needed). On the NTAG 424 DNA tag (or better in the file) you need a placeholder of 32 characters but only the first half (16 characters, see above) are used for encryption and transmission, the second half (which is "virtually overwritten) will not get transferred so there is no decryption on receiver side. You don't get the "padding" back.